# Convert null in "" inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, null

I have this code that works very nice and I don't want to change anything but add a new feature that I need, but not sure how...

This is the code:

```js
const Obj = {
    "0":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    "1":"Dali, Gaudí, Roberto Valconni",
};

const Obj3 = [];

var count = Obj[0].split('","').length;
var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
  
  var string = [];
  
  for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
    string.push(Obj[j].split('","')[i]);
  }
  
  Obj3[i] = string;
}

console.log(Obj3);
```

As I said the code works nice, my question is how I can add when in the Obj values there's a null value when converting the strings just change null to ""

Example with null value:

```js
    const Obj = {
        "0":"Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
        "1":null,
    };

    const Obj3 = [];

    var count = Obj[0].split('","').length;
    var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

    for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
      
      var string = [];
      
      for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
        string.push(Obj[j].split('","')[i]);
      }
      
      Obj3[i] = string;
    }

    console.log(Obj3);
```

As you can see it throws an error because of the null. My desired result should be this:

```
  [
    "Masaccio, Sandro Botticelli, Leonardo da Vinci",
    ""
  ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to conditionally use the value  or provide the default value before processing like `(Obj[i] || "")`

```js
const Obj = {
        "0":null,
        "1":null,
    };

    const Obj3 = [];

    var count = Obj[0]? Obj[0].split('","').length: 0;
    var countOuter = Object.keys(Obj).length;

    for( var i = 0; i < count; i++){
      
      var string = [];
      
      for( var j = 0; j < countOuter; j++){
        string.push((Obj[j] || "").split('","')[i]);
      }
      
      Obj3[i] = string;
    }

    console.log(Obj3);
```

Comment: Hello, @Shubham Khatri, your code works perfectly. It throws an error when the Obj is both null:

const Obj = {
        "0":null,
        "1":null
    };

Thanks! Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7mq0v8tf/

Comment: That happens because you try to split on the first key, Obj[0].split('","').length; You should add a condition there as well

Comment: Thank you, sir, you helped me a lot!! Much appreciated. The code works perfectly! Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use NPM package called [is-empty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-empty) where you can check the object like

`const output = (empty(Obj[i]) === true ? "", Obj[i])`

Beyond NULL it can also check for `undefined`, `false` etc.